# Rails Mongoid : Query embedded document and access to Mongoid criteria

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have an application where users can create many travels, and they can invite their facebook friends. In the travel document, there is a field "participants" that is an embedded document, `Participant` model embedded in `Travel` model.
[image: example]

Here are my models :

```
class Travel
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  # relations
  belongs_to :user

  # fields
  field :title, type: String
  field :description, type: String
  field :begin_date, type: Date
  field :end_date, type: Date
  field :budget, type: Integer
  field :go_back, type: Boolean
  field :title_namespace, type: String

  # friends
  embeds_many :participants
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :participants

end

class Participant
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :name, type: String
  field :user_id, type: String

  # relations
  embedded_in :travel, :inverse_of => :participants

end
```

When I try to display travel where users have been invited, with this request :

```
@travel_participations = Travel.where('participants.user_id' => @user.id)
```

I don't have any result, even if I have this line in byebug :

```
#<Mongoid::Criteria
  selector: {"participants.user_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('592c8da58511989ec850921e')}
  options:  {}
  class:    Travel
  embedded: false>
```

So when I put this on my view :

```
<% unless @participations.nil? %>
  <% @travel_participations.each do |travel_participation| %>
    <p> <%= travel_participation.title %> </p>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I tried with `.all`, `.first`, `.to_a`, `.as_json`, no results ... Some one know where is the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this in your embedded model:

```
field :user_id, type: String
```

but your query is using a `BSON::ObjectId`:

```
Travel.where('participants.user_id' => @user.id)
```

as shown in the raw query:

```
selector: {"participants.user_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('592c8da58511989ec850921e')}
```

Your embedded document probably has a *string* field like:

```
"user_id": "592c8da58511989ec850921e"
```

rather than the `ObjectId` you're looking for:

```
"user_id": ObjectId("592c8da58511989ec850921e")
```

so you won't find what you're looking for due to the type mismatch.

Either fix the embedded field's type:

```
field :user_id, type: BSON::ObjectId
```

or query it as the string it is:

```
Travel.where('participants.user_id' => @user.id.to_s)
```

Changing the type will involve fix up whatever data you already have, changing the query is ugly in a different way.

Sometimes Mongoid will convert between strings and ObjectIds for you, sometimes it won't. When I used Mongoid I patched `to_bson_id` methods into `BSON::ObjectId`, `String`, `Mongoid::Document`, ... so that I could say things like:

```
Model.where(:some_id => some_id.to_bson_id)
```

and not have to constantly worry about what type `some_id` was. I also made sure that all ID fields were always specified as `BSON::ObjectId`.

Comment: Perfect answer, it is clear and I have explanation, lot of thanks for that buddy ! I mark your answer as accepted !

Comment: Well, an answer without an explanation doesn't teach very much, does it? And the difference between strings and ObjectIds is very annoying.